# Event fired when user redirects to home : exists?

Tags: community, url, lightning-events

Heyo all,

I am working on a Lightning Community. I need to detect whenever the user goes to the main page (clicking page logo, home ling, whatever...).
I tried the following events :

```
<aura:handler event='force:refreshView' action='{!c.myAction}'/>    
<aura:handler event='force:navigateHome' action='{!c.myAction}'/>
```

But neither of these do what I need, and the documentation explained me why. Is there any way to detect when the user is redirected to a given page ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried enabling [Salesforce lightning Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-lightning-insp/pcpmcffcomlcjgpcheokdfcjipanjdpc?hl=en) to see which event is fired when you click the home button. The event fired is `siteforce:viewChanged`

[image: Home Click Event Fired]

Then I tried adding a listener for that event ,

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:handler event="siteforce:viewChanged " action="{!c.doRedirect}"></aura:handler>
</aura:component>
```

When I try to save it, I get compile time error:

```
Failed to save ViewChangeEvent.cmp: Invalid Descriptor Format: siteforce:viewChanged [EVENT]: Source
```

It looks like `siteforce:viewChanged` is private for Salesforce namespace and we cannot listen to it, thus I don't think there a way todetect when the user is redirected to a given page.